# SQL Server Configuration While installation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, connection, tcp

My application’s bootstraper downloads and install SQL Server Express, up to this part everything is fine.  My issues are:

1. I want to install it with such parameter that the sa password is set as my given password, instead user has to use SSMSE and change it.
2. In Status, Setting are done automatically as ‘Permission to Connect to DB Engine is Grant and ‘Login’  is Enabled (by default it is Disabled)
3. SQL Server Browser Service should be ‘running’
4. User should not need to use SQL Server Surface Area Config.and It should automatically set to ‘Local and Remote Connections’ with Using TCP / IP only’

Please advise how to achieve these goals.

Thanks

Comment: What parts of your question are not answered by Microsoft's documentation? http://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql+server+unattended&rlz=1C1CHLW_enAU510AU510&aq=f&oq=sql+server+unattended&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for comments ! I wonder how to do 1,2 and 4

Comment: There is no need to wonder. Take 1 for example. The first link on Google is the Microsoft documentation. Search for `/SAPWD` and read the description: *Specifies the password for the SQL Server sa account.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Installation How-To Topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281837.aspx) on MSDN is a fairly comprehensive reference for installing SQL Server. In particular, the following child pages have plenty of information on deploying SQL Server in customised configurations:

- [Install SQL Server 2012 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)
- [Install SQL Server 2012 Using a Configuration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx)
- [Install SQL Server 2012 Using SysPrep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210664.aspx)

If the customisation you require is not offered by one of those steps, you should identify which one most meets your requirements and treat the remaining configuration of the SQL Server instance and support services as a separate problem.

That is to say, you may need to deploy SQL Server in two steps (e.g. using a configuration file, and then running some shell commands afterwards to complete the configuration).